# body background image stretch height in iphone5

Tags: jquery, html, css, responsive-design, iphone-5

I am facing a serious problem in Iphone5 compatibility. I don't know what's the problem in Iphone5 cause when I check any other mobile device the body background image not stretched but when I check in Iphone5 the problem occurred.

Here is the website link.

http://divinotech.com/verp_new/

Comment: It's the combo of `background-size` and `background position`. I suggest you drop `background-size` and change `background-position` to `top center`. Not the same effect, but I think it'll fix the iphone problem.

Comment: I do that but the image was not comeing in full height....